# SQLite no such table error when using 2 tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing an Android project where I use a database with more than 1 table. I first tried with one table and everything worked fine, but when I'm using a second table I have an error.
Here is the code:
This part works perfectly fine:

```
public class MarqueDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reprise.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "create table marque (name text primary key)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "drop table if exists marque";

public MarqueDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
public class ModeleDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reprise.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "create table modele (name text primary key)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "drop table if exists modele";

public ModeleDBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

The error occurs when I do an insert here:

```
public class ModeleDAO {
private Context context;
private ModeleDBHelper modeleHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public ModeleDAO(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

public void addMarque(ArrayList<Modele> marqueListe){
    modeleHelper = new ModeleDBHelper(context);
    db = modeleHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for(Modele str : marqueListe){
        values.put("name", str.getNom());
        db.insertWithOnConflict("modele", null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

    }

    db.close();
    modeleHelper.close();
}
}
```

Here is the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: modele (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR IGNORE  INTO modele(name) VALUES (?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
at quentin.android.fastback2.DataAccess.ModeleDAO.addMarque(ModeleDAO.java:31)
at quentin.android.fastback2.DataAccess.SyncAdapter$3.onResponse(SyncAdapter.java:143)
at quentin.android.fastback2.DataAccess.SyncAdapter$3.onResponse(SyncAdapter.java:125)
at quentin.android.fastback2.Model.CustomRequest.deliverResponse(CustomRequest.java:42)
at quentin.android.fastback2.Model.CustomRequest.deliverResponse(CustomRequest.java:16)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I've tried a couple of things, like changing the database version, uninstall/reinstall the app and using an other device emulator (I'm using Genymotion)
I checked the database file, the table "marque" is well created but not the table "modele". It's like the OnCreate() method from ModeleDBHelper is never called.  Thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need to create 2 separate DB helpers. Only one will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` versions database files, not tables. If you have more than one table in the same database file, put them all in the same `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

After merging the helpers, uninstall your app so that the old database file is removed and the `onCreate()` that creates all tables is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a database with the same name `"reprise.db"` , the on create method is never called for your second helper (as the database file already exists). so the table is never created

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){ // Never called
   db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}
```

As suggested, you should merge them to overcome this issue.

So your oncreate method would create Both tables.